# Raspberry pi 3B using Yolov88 takes 4 seconds to do any detection

Tags: python, opencv, yolo, yolov8

so im using rasbperry pi 3b to detect fires using yolov8 but while using it with open cv it takes a lot to just analyze 1 photo and i have a problem with that, it takes old frames from the video to analyze not the current frame like it takes a 24 frame video and i'm now in the 24th frame and it analyzes the 1st frame in 4 to 5 seconds then it don't jump to the 24th frame no it analyzes the 2nd frame so it takes soooo long to get to the frames where the fire exists and it's not an optimum solution my code:

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
import cvzone
import cv2
import math




# Running real time from webcam
cap = cv2.VideoCapture (0)
model = YOLO('best.pt')


# Reading the classes
classnames = ['fire']

while True:
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame,(640,480))
    result = model(frame,stream=True)

    # Getting bbox,confidence and class names informations to work with
    for info in result:
        boxes = info.boxes
        for box in boxes:
            confidence = box.conf[0]
            confidence = math.ceil(confidence * 100)
            Class = int(box.cls[0])
            if confidence > 50:
                x1,y1,x2,y2 = box.xyxy[0]
                x1, y1, x2, y2 = int(x1),int(y1),int(x2),int(y2)
                cv2.rectangle(frame,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),5)
                cvzone.putTextRect(frame, f'{classnames[Class]} {confidence}%', [x1 + 8, y1 + 100],
                                   scale=1.5,thickness=2)




    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

i tried changing the resolution but nothing changes